# Read next value in XML file

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, readxml

I have a XML file like that:

```
    <key>businessAddress</key>
    <string>Moka</string>
    <key>businessName</key>
    <string>Moka address</string>
    <key>Id</key>
    <string>39</string>
    <key>Cat</key>
    <string>216</string>
    <key>deals</key>
```

I want to read the next `<string>` value if the key is Id

So what I did is this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(file);

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value.Equals("Id"))
    {
        reader.MoveToNextAttribute
    }  
}
```

but I didn't succeed.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean flag to indicate whether you should read the value of the next element:

```
bool shouldReadId = false;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && shouldReadId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value); // will print 39
        shouldReadId = false;
    }

    if (reader.Value.Equals("Id"))
    {
        // indicate that we should read the value of the next element
        // in the next iteration
        shouldReadId = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point that [XmlTextReader is basically replaced with XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the
>   System.Xml.XmlReader class instead.

Though their object model doesn't differ in any significant way.

So, if you want to use XmlTextReader you can do something like:

```
public static class XmlReaderExtensions
{
    public static void EnsureRead(this XmlTextReader reader)
    {
        var isRead = reader.Read();
        if (!isRead)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to read");
    }

    public static void SkipUntil(this XmlTextReader reader, Func<XmlTextReader, Boolean> isStop)
    {
        while (!isStop(reader))
        {
            reader.EnsureRead();
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
var xml = @"<root>   <key>businessAddress</key>
    <string>Moka</string>
    <key>businessName</key>
    <string>Moka address</string>
    <key>Id</key>
    <string>39</string>
    <key>Cat</key>
    <string>216</string>
    <key>deals</key> </root>";

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
{
    reader.SkipUntil(cur => cur.Value == "Id");
    reader.EnsureRead(); // Skip current node
    reader.SkipUntil(cur => cur.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("The id from XmlTextReader is {0}", reader.Value);
}
```

Though to be sure that it will <del>work correctly</del> fail fast with some xml, that doesn't correspond to the given schema, you will have to add a bit more of sanity checks, so...

---

You can also try [LINQ-TO-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) if you are not concerned with entire xml tree being put into the memory:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    var id = xdoc
        .Root
        .Elements("key")
        .First(element =>
            element.Value == "Id")
        .ElementsAfterSelf("string")
        .First()
        .Value;
    Console.WriteLine("The id from XDocument is {0}", id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML looks suspiciously similar to [Plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html). So, sounds like you need a Plist library. Instead of reinventing the wheel, just use [any of the libraries available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=plist). They'll solve your problems with parsing the XML file.

If you insist on parsing XML manually, forget about the low-level SAX class and just use DOM. Working with `XDocument` is much easier. See **@EugenePodskal**'s solution.